# What cancelled ABC (US) TV show is Seth Meyers talking about in this comedic monologue?

Tags: comedy

In Seth Meyers' recent "Back in My Day" monologue [Back in My Day: O.J. Simpson on Twitter, BTS](https://youtu.be/BiAWcnZcrco?t=163) at about `02:43` he says:

> Back in my day, people weren’t getting cancelled online for saying something stupid or racist. Back in my day if you said something stupid or racist, you got cancelled by ABC. But then, they tried to bring your show back without you, but it was tricky, because your name was in the title. In fact, it was the title. [Laughter]

Which cancelled ABC (American Broadcasting Company) TV show is he describing?

I would think that it could be [Roseanne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roseanne) except that the idea behind "Back in My Day" is that he is referring to things that happened decades ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He is referencing the 2018 revival of the 1988 sitcom *[Roseanne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roseanne)*, which was cancelled after its star, Roseanne Barr, made questionable comments on twitter.

Comment: I suspected that (and mentioned it in the question) except that 2018 is too recent to fit the "Back in My Day" theme that everything else in the skit seems to fit. Could there also be a different ABC series that cancelled a long time ago? Or am I being overly strict about the "Back in My Day" theme?

Comment: @uhoh He doesn't actually limit himself completely to older stuff in the bit. For example, the K-pop bands he rattles off towards the end are contemporary ones, and he references the internet as well.

Comment: Oh, I now see what you mean. This clears up a lot, thanks!